# window scroll function is firing even when scrolling top

Tags: javascript

I have used this

`if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100)
{   alert("scrolled down to the bottom!");    }`

It is  working in both way  either  scrolling up or down.

I need  it to fire only when reached to the bottom. what should I do here ?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML, CSS and JavaScript? If I test your code it works for me. In order to test your code more, we need more of the original code.